# Listing of New York Times celebrity crosswords?

Tags: crosswords, reference-request

The New York Times crossword for Friday May 12 was co-authored by Bill Clinton, as part of an ongoing series of celebrity crosswords.  Actor Jesse Eisenberg did one too.

Is there a way to get a list of all the celebrity-authored crosswords this year to date?

Thanks,

Comment: I suspect that this is off-topic for this stack, but have you tried writing to the New York Times?

Comment: Hey @Jeff Zeitlin  No, I never thought to just write them.  I also suspect this is off topic for this stack.  Sorry stack masters!

Answer (score 1):

The search function on the NYTimes site helped with this, I couldn't find a full list only the short ones on the wiki page. (Same goes for other sites, they just cherry-pick the ones they like).

https://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/celebrity+crossword/since1851/allresults/1/allauthors/relevance/Crosswords%2FGames/

Comment: Thanks @BreakingMyself. I think you're right that there's perhaps not a way to get a single listing without scrolling through some commentaries.